# Accessing multilevel dictionary using C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure like below. I want to write a code that will help me in accessing the objects from the 2nd level and 3rd level of the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

I have something of this form now.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\xyz.csv"))
{
   string line;
   line = r.ReadLine();
   while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
   {
          line = r.ReadLine();
   }
   string[] sHeaders = line.Split(',');
   int iIndex = Array.IndexOf(sHeaders, "RollNo");
   while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] records = line.Split(',');
        string sname = records[iIndex];
        foreach (string record in records)
        {

            while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sname))
            {
                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> columns = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();


                 // Dont know what to do here
             }
        }

   }
```

xyz.csv

```
RollNo Name Subject1
1      abc   90
2      xyz   80
3      pqr   92
//emptyline
RollNo Name Subject2
1      abc   98
2      xyz   86
3      pqr   88
//emptyline
RollNo Name Subject3
1      abc   99
2      xyz   83
3      pqr   82
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated .. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: At this point, wouldn't it be easier to just create objects matching your domain? I mean, it's not that basic data structures are not fun to use, but C# is an OO language, it's nice to use that power. A three-layered dictionary is not a useful thing to do really...

Comment: I had a similar situation. And i decided to use jagged arrays for this. Was much better and I suppose also faster. Would like to know wether this assumption is right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is a really bad design but here is a sample:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{
    var currentDictionary = dict[key];
    foreach (var key2 in currentDictionary.Keys)
    {
        var nestedDictionary = currentDictionary[key2];
        foreach (var item in nestedDictionary)
        {
            var currentKey = item.Key;
            var currentValue = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As @Selman22 says the performance on this sucks, iterating over dictionaries is very slow - if possible convert these to lists or ideally arrays if you're doing lots of iterations rather than lookups.